# Use of global variables in a Python script

Tags: python

I am relatively inexperienced in python.  I made a small custom function to record logs to a remote file as a single block of text every time a script executes:

```
global logContent
DEBUG = 'debug'
INFO = 'info'
ERROR = 'error'

def logMessage(level, message):
    global logContent
    logContent += f'{<timestamp>} - {level}: {message}\n'

def flushLogsToDB():
    ...

logMessage(INFO, 'script executes here')
flushLogsToDB()
```

The idea is to hide the implementation behind passing the variable `logContent` around, and then sending it off in a single API call.

Since normally I work with more object-oriented languages, I'm not sure if this is 'okay' in the current context.  Normally I know global variables are the devil, but since this script executes idempotently, as far as "best practices" is this okay?

Definitely looking for some resources on general Python best practices as well.

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: There are a number of ways you could handle this.  One would be to use a logger class such as [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).  If for some reason you don't want that, you could also create a closure, binding your logging function to a specific log variable.  I think the class solution is better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anybody is going to defend this practice, when the alternative is cleaner and not at all a lot more complicated.

```
class Mylog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []

    def log_message(self, message):
        self.content.append(message)

    def flush(self):
        ... something with self.content
        self.content = []
```

Creating a new `Mylog` instance will of course create an object with a similar scope as your current `logContent`; but the encapsulation of the functionality also hides the method names from global scope, and allows you to have multiple `Mylog` instances if you wanted to.

For this particular use case, maybe look at extending the existing `logging` module from the Python standard library.

Comment: Yeah. The more I think about it the more I realize how backwards I was approaching this. Thanks!